# How to prevent Samsung ROM from showing notification bar in full screen?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-notification-bar, notification-bar

I have this app that runs in full screen, the thing is that Samsung did something to their ROMs that the user can swipe down to show the notification bar, even that you are running in full screen. The thing is that my app shouldn't show the notification bar when running in full screen.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Seems unlikely. It sounds like the whole point of Samsung's change was to avoid the behavior that you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What behavior? Run in full screen?

Comment: Not showing the notification bar in full screen.

Comment: That's exactly the point of running any app in full screen.

Comment: Have exactly the same problem. Even worse! I have an UI element on the top of the screen that comes down by swiping it. In the Samsung Galaxy Note 2, it's opening the status bar. How can one manufacturer kill the full screen feature like this?!

Comment: @Rui I know, if you download my app Ubuntu Lockscreen you can see why I want to eliminate this issue!